# A Number Theory Reduction

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

If we know the value of  $a\pmod {p_1}$ and $b\pmod {p_2}$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime, is it possible to find the value of $ab\pmod {p_1p_2}$ ? . I was thinking of using the chinese remainder theorem but I can't seem to generalize it.

Comment: If $p_{1} \ne p_{2}$, use CRT to get the values of $a$ and $b$ modulo $p_{1} p_{2}$, then you're done. If $p = p_{1} = p_{2}$, you cannot determine the result, as you can see by taking first $a = b = 1$, and then $a = 1 +p$, $b = 1$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti sorry for the inconvenience but I have changed the question a bit.

Comment: No problemo ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention CRT, I assume $p_{1} \ne p_{2}$.

The answer is no.

Think of $a = 1 + s p_{1}$ (all values are congruent modulo $p_{1}$), $b = 1 + t p_{2}$ (all values are congruent modulo $p_{2}$), which yield
all the products
$$
ab \equiv 1 + s p_{1} + t p_{2} \pmod{p_{1} p_{2}}.
$$

For instance when $p_{1} = 3$ and $p_{2} = 5$ we have
$$
 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \not\equiv 9 \equiv (1 + 3) (1 + 5) \pmod{15}.
$$

Comment: Note that since $\,p_1,p_2\,$ are coprime, by Bezout we can choose $\,s,t\,$ so $\,sp_1+tp_2\,$ is any integer, therefore $\,ab\,$ can take *every* value mod $\,p_1p_2.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, great comment, thanks!